# Why is complex class not optimized to cache objects in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, complex-numbers

As far as I can see normally Python will cache objects to optimize memory usage. For example:

```
>>> a = 7
>>> b = 7
>>> hex(id(a)) == hex(id(b))
True
```

It even works for strings. So I wonder why it isn't the case for `complex` objects when they are built-in objects and I believe that they should be optimized as much as possible.

```
>>> a = 1+3j
>>> b = 1+3j
>>> hex(id(a)) == hex(id(b))
False
```

Is it on purpose or is internal representation of `complex` numbers somehow too *complex* to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is a function to show the memory position of an object. All Python integers from `-5` to `256` [are cached in memory](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/longobject.c) for reutilization (they are immutable objects anyway) so the first example you showed is expected to have the same `id` for both `a` and `b`. If you try with bigger integers, you will not have this result because generating ints will not cache anything. Just those integers were cached beforehand.

On the second example, the interpreter generates a different complex number object on each call to `1 + 3j` because there's also no caching in this operation.

PS: An easier way to check this is with the `is` keyword:

```
>>> a = 9992
>>> b = 9992
>>> a is b
False
```

Sometimes, these things can happen:

```
>>> 9992 is 9992
True
```

This is because on CPython's Peephole Optimizer, it uses the same constant to load both versions of `9992` and then compare it. Check the dissassembled code below (both `LOAD_CONST` uses the index `1` referring to the same object).

```
>>> def f():
...    return 9992 is 9992

>>> dis.dis(f)
2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (9992)
            3 LOAD_CONST               1 (9992)
            6 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
            9 RETURN_VALUE
```

On a matter of strings, CPython (on versions 2.6 and better) have an auto [`intern`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#intern) feature to also cache some results. But it is not guaranteed for you to have the same object every time you write the same string and no chance at all when you have string operations such as concatenating.

---

Reading Ashwini Chaudhary comments, I realized people might confuse constant optimization ("Compile time")  and object caching ("Run Time"). On a Python file, if you do the tests above, they might return true because the optimizer sees the same number twice and creates a CONST, as illustrated on the dissassembled code above. But this only happens on the same scope.

To prove that, you can have the following code on a `.py` file and you will see the integers will not be cached

```
def f():
    return 777

def g():
    return 777

print(f() is g())
```

Comment: CPython also caches literals, for example  `x = 300; y=300; print x is y` will print `True`. I guess that's what OP is referring to as they have also mentioned strings.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary At least on Python3 this code will print False.

Comment: Don't run it in shell, use a normal `.py` file. Also your answer is not answering the actual question: *Why is complex class not optimized to cache objects in Python?*

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary The premise OP uses is invalid. The int class is also not optimized to cache. What you see on a `.py` file is the same as the function I showed above (the constants in the file are being optimized).

Comment: Inside a function `x = 300; y=300; print x is y` prints `True` in both Python 2 and 3. And complex literals too use the `LOAD_CONST` bytecode, if they are in the same scope why isn't CPython caching them there?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Ok, now I understand your point. I would believe it is because integer math is far more important to be cached than complex math (more common so there is more gain into caching). Also because transforming an operation `1+3j` into a constant might occur later on optmization, but I have not checked the code